# Styling elements as selected onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I turn an element like this:

```
<a href="#" class="select" id="select">Element1</a>
<a href="#" class="select" id="select">Element2</a>
<a href="#" class="select" id="select">Element3</a>
```

To be like a selected button, for example, Its normal look be

```
.select {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

But if I clicked on one element of them it turn to be

```
.select {
   background-color: red;
}
```

But the trick I want to learn here is, How can I make it only one element being able to have the style, Like a radio buttons, Only one button to have the selected style, and if I clicked on another button, the style be removed from the previous one and be at the clicked one, Using JavaScript and CSS only if possible

Comment: as a side note DONT use multiple ids with the same value.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw ids aren't used in the same way of classes?

Comment: if the intention here is just to give meaning to the tag it's applied to then that's fine even though it is not recommended, However, when targeting elements with the same ids in javascript only the first one will be targetted or with CSS. to put it simply, ids are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//get all buttons
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("select");

function clicker() {
  //loop through all buttons
  for (y = 0; y < btns.length; ++y) {
    //if button is not the current button remove the background class
    if (btns[y].classList.contains && btns[y] != this) {
      btns[y].classList.remove("colorize")
    } //end if
    //add background class to current button
    this.classList.add("colorize");
  }
}
//add an event handler to all buttons
for (x = 0; x < btns.length; ++x) {
  btns[x].addEventListener("click", clicker)
}
```

```css
.select {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.colorize {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="select">Element1</a>
<a href="#" class="select">Element2</a>
<a href="#" class="select">Element3</a>
```

Comment: This method seems unneccessarily complicated if i'm honest, it doesn't use jQuery though I guess. However the OP included the jQuery tag so I assume he's using it,

Comment: True but he said "Using JavaScript and CSS only if possible"

Comment: Yep my bad, didn't see that

Comment: I really want to pick your answer and @Md. Shariful Islam answer both Because they solve the problem in both ways, Out if that, in speed and performance matter, Which one is faster? Yours or Md.Shariful?

Comment: Pure javascript is faster (also how you optimize your codes) but the codes are lengthy when compared to jquery..However building a solid foundation with javascript will gave you an edge since jquery is just a javascript library

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:- First, remove **selected** class from all the links and then add **selected** class to that clicked link **(using jQuery).**

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="select" id="select1">Element1</a>
<a href="#" class="select" id="select2">Element2</a>
<a href="#" class="select" id="select3">Element3</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.select {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.selected {
   background-color: red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select').click(function(){
        $('.select').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
})
```

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/codebazz/w22rpj2k/)

Comment: Dear, down voter feel free to add a comment too. That would be more appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: I really don't know why did this get down voted, It is the simplest way to explain how to do it in jQuery, I really want to pick your answer & @repzero answer both.

Comment: It does not matter if it gets thousand down votes. I am happy that it helps you at least. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this quite easily using JavaScript and the addClass() method.

Firstly, don't use the same ID for multiple elements.

## HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="select" id="Element1">Element1</a>
<a href="#" class="select" id="Element2">Element2</a>
<a href="#" class="select" id="Element3">Element3</a>
```

## CSS:

```
.select {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.clicked {
    background-color: red;
}
```

## JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".select").click(function () {
    $(".select").addClass("clicked");
});

});
```

## Note this method uses jQuery